# Java programming standard deviation error in code

Tags: java

My standard deviation is way off. When I enter:
2 4 4 4 5 5 7 9 n

I don't get 2. This is my code. I believe everything checks out so I don't understand why I keep getting 1.8284791953425266 instead of 2 :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stocks {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     double currentNum = 0;
     double numtotal = 0;
     int count = 0;
     double mean = 0;
     double square = 0, squaretotal = 0, sd = 0;

     System.out.println("Enter a series of double value numbers, ");
     System.out.println("Enter anything other than a number to quit: ");

     while (in.hasNextDouble()) 
     {

         currentNum = in.nextDouble();
         numtotal = numtotal + currentNum;

         count++;
         mean = (double) numtotal / count;
         square = Math.pow(currentNum - mean, 2.0);
         squaretotal = squaretotal + square; 
         sd = Math.pow(squaretotal/count, 1/2.0);
     }

     System.out.println("The mean is: " +mean);
     System.out.println("The standard deviation is: " +sd);

     }


 }
```

Comment: [The standard deviation for that set is 2.13, actually.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Standard+deviation%3A+%7B2+4+4+4+5+5+7+9%7D)

Comment: I'm using this definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation so I'm dividing by n not (n-1) in the square root sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work out the mean for all the numbers before you work out the standard deviation.
Right now your mean is the average of all numbers up to the current number. Your problem is here

```
square = Math.pow(currentNum - mean, 2.0);
```

At this point the mean is the average of the numbers we've seen. This is because numtotal is the total of the numbers we've seen. To fix this you can take in all the numbers first into something like an array-list. Then work out the mean with all the numbers and after that you can work out the square differences and so the standard deviation.

Comment: This can be done almost as a recursive tree system if need be: `avg(avg(a, b), avg(c, d)) = (a+b+c+d)/4`

Comment: Also, if I could be so blunt as to show where he messed up that'd be great. To get the average of numbers by calculating average as you go leads to a peculiar advancement. Say we declare: `d = avg(a, b)`, by that standard, to add 'c' into the average properly we would have to do this: `e = (d * 2 + c) / 3`. This can be expressed as a formula: `avg = avg(nums[])/nums.length + next`. If you do a series expansion on that, you come to the realization that you end up dividing by 2, then multiplying by 2 and so on. Common misconception.

Comment: @Legend I don't think that's the problem here. The problem is that the square difference between each number and the mean is being calculated with the mean for the numbers we've seen so far instead of the final mean. The value of the mean itself is fine by the end of the loop.

Comment: The value of the mean isn't 'fine' as I pointed out in the comments. The weightings are different as you sweep through.

Comment: Look at the code posted. Mean isn't being calculated with the previous mean in a recursive way, only in the standard way with total and count. By the end of the loop total has all the numbers and count is the number of numbers read. So once the loop completes mean is correct. The mean before that is incorrect but only because not all of the numbers have been read yet.

Answer (score 0):

`count` needs to be a double if you're going to divide by it.

```
mean = (double) numtotal / count;
```

-->

```
mean = (double) numtotal / (double) count;
```

Comment: I wrote up some papers about introduction to primitive data types a while ago and I think it might apply here: The double type is like a virus, all other types when performed an operation on become a double. Also, converting from a double to any other type requires a `(double)` cast.